# Loop over json files inside subdirectories

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a folder with subfolders in it. I try to loop over each subfolder and import json files in mongo database:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in /data/Mydata/*/; 
do
    ls -1 *.json | while read jsonfile; 
    do 
        mongoimport --db MyApp --collection logs --file $jsonfile --type json
        done;
done;
```

But this gives me an error:

```
ls: cannot access *.json: No such file or directory
```

If I am inside each subdirectory and do:

```
ls -1 *.json | while read jsonfile; 
do 
    mongoimport --db MyApp --collection logs --file $jsonfile --type json
done;
```

It works.

What am I doing wrong? I am quite new to Ubuntu.
Best Regards

Comment: I can't tell if this bit is correct `/data/Mydata/*/` but in the `do` line you need to reference the variable like: `ls -1 "$dir"/*.json | while read jsonfile;` or bash has no idea where to look

Comment: Hi, I then get `ls: cannot access /data/Mydata/*//*.json: No such file or directory`

Comment: are you sure this `data/Mydata` directory is under `/`? is it actually in your home like `~/data/Mydata`? do `ls ~/data/Mydata` - you see your directories there? I think that is the problem

Comment: @Zanna `ls /data/Mydata` is correct. So the subdirectories are in `/data/MyData`, i.e. `ls /data/Mydata/Stuff` is correct.

Comment: hmm I don't know then, but parsing `ls` is a bad idea, hopefully someone who understands better what you're trying to do will come and fix your script

Comment: You had some answer with `f` variable, maybe that did work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45261/discussion-between-zanna-and-user1665355).

Comment: Where you have `while read jsonfile` are you trying to reference each .json file that you've found?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't referenced the "`dir`" from your `for` line in your `do` line, so bash doesn't know where to look for the `*.json` files that are in `"$dir"`

You could simplify by just matching the files:

```
for jsonfile in /data/Mydata/*/*.json ; 
do
    mongoimport --db MyApp --collection logs --file "$jsonfile" --type json
done;
```

And thanks @terdon for fixing this so you don't have to parse ls, which is a [very bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) - avoid that in future!

Comment: `for dir in /data/Mydata/* ;` gives: `ls: cannot access /data/Mydata/*/*.json: No such file or directory`, and `for dir in /data/Mydata/*/* ; ` gives `ls: cannot access /data/Mydata/*/*/*.json: No such file or directory`. But files are inside `/data/Mydata`...

Comment: No sorry, subdirectories are inside `/data/Mydata`. So for example I can have a subdirectory `/data/Mydata/Stuff`, inside where .json files are.

Comment: +1 for repeating that parsing `ls` is a bad idea!

Comment: thanks @Arronical :) but the caution is not much use without providing the appropriate alternative. Unfortunately I'm not sure what the whole script is meant to do

Comment: I love the wooledge link! It looks like the script is finding all .json files and importing them into a mongo database. I had some odd behaviour from AU, couldn't see your answer, so wrote my own, then it said your answer had been posted an hour ago, Monday morning gremlins methinks.

Comment: @Arronical :) your answer gets my vote since it avoids the dreaded `ls` parse. Probably they will be OK here if they don't have any weird filenames :S

Answer (score 7):

I think the `find`command should achieve your goal, the script would become:

```
#!/bin/bash

find /data/Mydata/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -iname "*.json" -type f -exec mongoimport --db MyApp --collection logs --file "{}" --type json \;
```

This will only access direct subdirectories of `/data/Mydata`, due to the `maxdepth` and `mindepth` settings. `"{}"` gets expanded to the name of the file found each time, and the `mongoimport` command is run each time a file is found.

I've insured that the `mongoimport` command won't run on any directories that may be named `something.json` by using `-type f` which limits the find result to files, I imagine you wont have any directories named like this, but it's just a precaution